# Avoid macro to be usable from client code

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm currently working on a header only library and I'd like to be able to use some macros without them being usable from client code. Example:

```
// library_header1.h

#define MACRO_NUMBER_1(__X__) doSomethingWith(__X__) // etc...

class LibraryClass1
{
    // We'll use the macro somewhere in here.
};
```

Now, if I include library_header1.h i'm able to use MACRO_NUMBER_1. Is there any way I can avoid that?

Comment: `#undef` seems to work fine, but I'd also like to know if there's any way that macros are not defined (so that autocomplete/intellisense doesn't show them).

Comment: You are providing your library in source form. You cannot hope to keep the implementation hidden. It is up to the Intellisense implementation whether or not it will show the macro. For Microsoft's compilers you can check to see if using [`#pragma push_macro`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bs04eza.aspx)/`pop_macro` has any effect on Intellisense implementations.

Comment: you can use pre-build post-build events in visual studio to enable the macro only during compilation and avoid intellisense. check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/42x5kfw4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Others already mentioned `#undef` but what if you have many macros you need to undefine and you need to use them in many headers? This situation can be dealt with by having a header define and undefine macros and bewteen that include a specified header. For example:

```
// temp-macros.h
#if defined(OUTER)
#  define MACRO x
#  include OUTER
#  undef MACRO
#  undef OUTER
#endif
```

The idea is to set up `OUTER` from the header where the macros are neede, include `temp-macros.h` and use the macros in the second inclusion:

```
// macro-use.h
#if !defined(OUTER)
#  define OUTER "macro-use.h"
#  include "temp-macros.h"
#elif !defined(INCLUDED_MACRO_USE)
#  define INCLUDED_MACRO_USE
void use(int MACRO) { /*...*/ }
#endif
```

Of course, this example uses just one trivial macro but if there are more macros and they are more complicated this approach could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the library user from accessing the macro - you can put `#undef` when you know you won't need your macro anymore.

If you want to prevent intellisense/autocompletion from ever seeing your macro, you may try to trick it by skipping it over the macro definition. Usually you can do it as follows:

- set up your compilation project (visual solution, makefile, ...) so that you pass an extra "identification" macro. Something like `-DIAMCOMPILING`
- Guard your macro definition with `#ifdef IAMCOMPILING ... #endif`

your IDE will most likely not recognise `IAMCOMPILING` and skip over the definition of your macro.

Do note however, that then IDE will get confused when your actually use the macro in the header file and some nonexistent errors will be flagged.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it won't stop the macro from being noticed by the IDE, if you use a unusual prefix to the macro, it will be less likely to collide with something that the user will want to do, and thus be less offensive. It may not be the ideal solution, but prefixing the macro with CCC or XWX or something else that is unlikely to be used by the normal programmer may help.

(Or, don't use macros is always a solution that works!)

Comment: Nice thinking. However, the prefixing with unusual character combinations will fail when using for example Visual Assist's [Acronyms](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/acronym.asp). Suddenly, all of your unusual combinations will be potential user input. Plus, I'd be happy to see a non-macro version that evaluates `__LINE__` properly. Occasionally, macros are a necessity.